# JavaScript slideshow isn't working as intended

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I made this little Slideshow with HTML/CSS/JS. Most of it is working but there is one thing which I can't figure out. **How do I make it so the text above each image fits the img itself when autosliding is on? Right now it only shows the right title for each img when i manually click through.**  Any help is appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

```js
var uniqueRandoms = [];
var indexCount = 0;
var allImagesAndText = ["Seltene römische Goldmünze", "Römische Funde", "Römische Wandmalerei", "Tutanchamun", "Cheops Pyramide", "Ägyptische Malerei"];
var total = allImagesAndText.length - 1;

function makeUniqueRandom() {
  if (!uniqueRandoms.length) {
    for (var i = indexCount; i <= total; i++) {
      uniqueRandoms.push(i);
    }
  }
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * uniqueRandoms.length);
  var val = uniqueRandoms[index];

  uniqueRandoms.splice(index, 1);

  return val;
}

function slide(x) {
 if(indexCount + x >= 0 && indexCount + x <= total) {
  clearInterval(sliderInterval);
  indexCount += x;
  
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
   Image.src = "images/img" + indexCount + ".jpg";
  
  update_dom();
  

  sliderInterval = window.setInterval( slideA, 3000);
 }
}

function update_dom() {
 var left_holder = document.getElementById('left_holder');
 var right_holder = document.getElementById('right_holder');
 
 ChangeText(indexCount);
 
 if(indexCount == 0) {
  left_holder.style.display =  "none";
 } else if (indexCount == total) {
  right_holder.style.display = "none";
 } else {
  right_holder.style.display = "block";
  left_holder.style.display = "block";
 }
}

function slideA() {
  var Image = document.getElementById('img');
  imagescount = makeUniqueRandom();
  Image.src = "images/img" + imagescount + ".jpg";
  update_dom();
}

function ChangeText(imgNum) {
   document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = allImagesAndText[imgNum];
}

window.addEventListener("load", function() {
 update_dom();
   sliderInterval = window.setInterval( slideA, 3000);
   document.getElementById("right").addEventListener("click", function() {
    slide(1);
   });
  
   document.getElementById("left").addEventListener("click", function() {
    slide(-1);
   });
});
```

```css
#slideshow {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
#img {
  height: 450px;
  width: 650px;
}
#left_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
#right_holder {
  height: 450px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
.left {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 0px;
}
.right {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  right: 0px;
}
#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 32px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
  left: 37%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="slideshow">
  <div id="text1">Text</div>
  <img src="images/img0.jpg" />
  <div id="left_holder">
    <img id="left" class="left" src="images/arrow_left.png" />
  </div>
  <div id="right_holder">
    <img id="right" class="right" src="images/arrow_right.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make a jsFiddle so we can run your code. https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6jg48tzu/

Comment: Make it so we can see some images. (change links to online images) Your code should work completely.

Comment: i dont really know how to do that but i hope the "run code snippet" helps abit.

Comment: Your `img` tags reference local files and as such we can't see anything. And I'm not sure I understand your problems. What do you mean by 'title fitting the image'? Do you mean that it doesn't display the correct title?

Comment: @CanIbanoglu yes that is what i meant.

Comment: How are your images named? Is the first one `img1.jpg`? Is it `img0.jpg`? If it is `img1.jpg` that might be causing an [off by one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) that is displaying the wrong title.

Comment: here is a link to the 6 images with name+title http://imgur.com/a/XsbW2. my first img is img1.jpg

Comment: i renamed my images now starting from img0.jpg to img5.jpg that fixed some stuff but one problem remains: when the autoslide function turns on after 3seconds all titles are displayed wrong. (they only work if I click through the imgs).

Comment: A couple of other things, by [convention in JS](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html#names) only constructor functions should start with a capital letter. Also [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) is already an object defined by the DOM, you probably shouldn't use it as a variable name. If nothing else, it makes your code confusing to read. I would suggest using `img` or `image` instead.

Comment: What is the purpose of `makeUniqueRandom`? I'm having trouble making sense of it.

Comment: the purpose is to randomize the imgs after the 3 seconds when autoslide turns on. my only problem right now is that the title doesnt change for each img (while autoslide is on) means all 6 imgs have the same title and it doesn't change.